# To get file name using Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written batch file to extract last 8 character of multiple files in folder. But that batch file not giving desired result. My folder consist of below mentioned filenames sub_rachit_01.pdf and sub_kapoor_02.pdf. I want to extract rachit_01 and kapoor_02 as variable from folder. Batch File is shred below:

```
@echo off

set /p location=Please enter location of .pdf files:

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b %location%\*.pdf') do (
set filename=%%~na

set file=%filename:~-8%
echo %file%
)

pause
```

Comment: Change the **`%`** characters on your last two commands inside the parentheses to **`!`** characters.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment:

```bat
@Echo Off
:AskInput
ClS
Set "location="
Set /P "location=Please enter location of .pdf files: "
If Not Exist "%location%\*.pdf" GoTo AskInput

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%A In ("%location%\*.pdf") Do (Set "filename=%%~nA"
    Set "filename=!filename:~-8!"
    Echo !filename!)

Pause
```

I've replaced your `For /F` loop with a plain `For` loop, put a little bit of protection in there for the user input and removed the use of an additional variable, changing `filename` dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you `enabledelayedexpansion` but never use it. also `%%~na` will display name excluding extension. If the files all actually contains `sub_` you can search and replace instead.

```
@echo off

set /p location=Please enter location of .pdf files:

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b %location%\*.pdf') do (
set "filename=%%~na"
set "filename=!filename:sub_=!"
echo !filename!
)
endlocal
pause
```

by doing `for /?`

```
%~I                     Expands %I which removes any surrounding 
                    quotation marks ("").
%~fI                    Expands %I to a fully qualified path name.
%~dI                    Expands %I to a drive letter only.
%~pI                    Expands %I to a path only.
%~nI                    Expands %I to a file name only.
%~xI                    Expands %I to a file extension only.
%~sI                    Expands path to contain short names only.
%~aI                    Expands %I to the file attributes of file.
%~tI                    Expands %I to the date and time of file.
%~zI                    Expands %I to the size of file.
%~$PATH:I               Searches the directories listed in the PATH environment 
                    variable and expands %I to the fully qualified name of 
                    the first one found. If the environment variable name
```